# Pandas Drop Columns with Only One Unique Value for a Group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that consists of duplicate `id`:

```
id    text      text2     text3
1     hello     hello     hello
1     hello     hello     hello
2     hello     hello     goodbye
2     goodbye   hello     goodbye
2     hello     hello     goodbye
```

I want to remove columns where all values for an `id` are the same. This could mean that all values in the column are the same (`text2`) or all the values are the same for each `id` (`text3`).

Desired result:

```
id    text     
1     hello     
1     hello       
2     hello        
2     goodbye        
2     hello
```

I used this to identify the counts of unique values in each column:

```
df.apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))
```

If I drop all columns where this count is equal to 1, this would take care of the `text2` scenario. However, how should I take care of the `text3` scenario? The df has already been grouped by id to find duplicate, but do I need to use `groupby` again?

As a "bonus", I wouldn't mind knowing how to identify where even one `id` has text that is all the same (i.e. `text`). I'm essentially trying to find which columns cause there to be duplicates.

Thank you for any and all insight you all might have!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're getting at. I want to remove `text3` because all values are the same for each id.

Comment: You're right - I edited it. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way.

Get unique values for each column

```
In [1227]: u = df.nunique()
```

Get if any column has single value in each `id` group

```
In [1228]: gu = gu = (df.groupby('id').agg('nunique') == 1).all()
```

Get the index aka column names for satisfying conditions,

`u[u == 1].index.union(gu[gu].index).drop('id')` Then, use `drop`

```
In [1229]: df.drop(u[u == 1].index.union(gu[gu].index).drop('id'), axis=1)
Out[1229]:
   id     text
0   1    hello
1   1    hello
2   2    hello
3   2  goodbye
4   2    hello
```

Details

```
In [1304]: u
Out[1304]:
id       2
text     2
text2    1
text3    2
dtype: int64

In [1305]: gu
Out[1305]:
id        True
text     False
text2     True
text3     True
dtype: bool

In [1306]: u[u == 1].index.union(gu[gu].index).drop('id')
Out[1306]: Index([u'text2', u'text3'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I believe this is actually dropping the `True` columns rather than the `False` columns. But it works in theory - thank you very much! Do you happen to have any idea about the "bonus" piece I added?

Comment: Sorry, just `text`. Essentially how to identify all columns except those that have multiple unique values for each and every `id`.

Comment: `(df.groupby('id').agg('nunique') > 1).all()` would do, but your data doesn't have a single column where for each id it has multiple values.

Comment: I guess it should be `any()` instead of `all()`: `(df.groupby('id').agg('nunique') > 1).any()` - isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases this function works for me:

```
def remove_single_unique_values(dataframe):

"""
Drop all the columns that only contain one unique value.
not optimized for categorical features yet.

"""    
cols_to_drop = dataframe.nunique()
cols_to_drop = cols_to_drop.loc[cols_to_drop.values==1].index
dataframe = dataframe.drop(cols_to_drop,axis=1)
return dataframe
```